# Grails 3.1 JSON-Views, rendering a Category Tree

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, gson, grails-3.1, json-view

I'm using Graisl 3.1.1, rest-api profile.
I'm trying to build a Category Tree but I haven some problems rendering the categories in JSON-Views.

I'm using json templates, one for the parent and another for the child.
Basically I want to generate a json for angular something like this:

[image: angularjs Category treet]

These is my code.

Any help?

[image: Stacktrace]

//domain

```
class Category {
  ObjectId id /* MongoDB */
  static hasMany = [categories: Category]
  String name
  ...
```

//controller

```
def directory(){
   def categories = Category.findAllByCategoriesIsNotNull([sort: 'name', order: 'asc'])
   respond categories
}
```

//directory.gson

```
import com.example.Category
model {
    Iterable<Category> categoryList
}
json {
  categories g.render(template: 'parent', collection: categoryList ?: [], var: 'category')
}
```

//_parent.gson

```
import com.example.Category
model {
  Category category
}
json {
  id   category.id.toString()
  name category.name
  categories g.render(template: "category/child", collection: category.categories ?: [], var: 'child')
}
```

The problem is the `categories` line above, I'm not sure what is the problem or my mistake.

//_child.gson

```
import com.example.Category
model {
  Category child
}
json {
  name child.name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably confident you are encountering the same fresh bug (fixed in grails-views@1.0.4) that I encountered a couple weeks ago, [#9720](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9720):

> it would appear that the relative path isn't recognized for g.render and the fully qualified path is required even when the template is located in the same directory as the calling gson file.

Instead of:

```
categories g.render(template: "category/child", collection: category.categories ?: [], var: 'child')
```

prepend a slash to the template:

```
categories g.render(template: "/category/child", collection: category.categories ?: [], var: 'child')
```

You may also need to change:

```
categories g.render(template: 'parent', collection: categoryList ?: [], var: 'category')
```

to:

```
categories g.render(template: '/category/parent', collection: categoryList ?: [], var: 'category')
```

Comment: I also updated compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.0.3" to compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.0.4" Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use in controller

> import grails.converters.JSON

and then

> render result as JSON

Comment: thanks for your answer! but I'm looking forward to use json-views feature instead that solution.

Comment: New plugin was released an hour ago. http://grails-plugins.org/#plugin/views-gradle  And I am sure you have seen documentations.  http://grails.github.io/grails-views/latest/